# Remove English supported language from App Store (React Native / Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app available in France and the app is only translated in French.
On the App Store, in app details, I see: Languages: French and English.

So, i want to remove English in supported language.

What I tried:

In App Store Connect, my App supported available language is French (only french) and it’s default language.

In app.json I have:

```
locales": { "fr": "./languages/fr.json" }
```

But it’s not working…

Anyone have a solution?

Because it is quite blocking for me, apple testing the application in English instead of French…

Thank you